# Check geolocation availability in cordova applications

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, motorola

I am working on a cordova based app with some extra functionality, using geolocation.

So, one of the first steps during startup is to to check if geolocation is enabled on the device. The check is using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition and wait for one of the callbacks.

But I just found out, that this JS code doesn't work as expected on all devices (tested on 2 Androids):

```
function checkPositionAvailability(){
    // tested both -> same result
    // var options = {maximumAge: 0, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy:true};
    var options = {maximumAge: 0, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy:false};

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(position){
            console.log('got a position:');
            // ok, geolocation is available
        },
        function(error){
            console.log('got an error:');
            console.log('code   : ' + error.code);
            console.log('message: ' + error.message);

            console.log('error.PERMISSION_DENIED    = ' + error.PERMISSION_DENIED);
            console.log('error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE = ' + error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE);
            console.log('error.TIMEOUT              = ' + error.TIMEOUT);
            console.log('error.UNKNOWN_ERROR        = ' + error.UNKNOWN_ERROR);

            if (error.code == error.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // -> notify user that geolocation could be enabled
            }
        },
        options);
}

checkPositionAvailability();
```

the expected behaviour when geolocation is disabled is: the error callback should be called immediately with a POSITION_UNAVAILABLE or PERMISSION_DENIED error code.
This was working on a ancient Huawei 8850 with Android 2.3.5. But not on my brand new Moto G with Android 4.4.4.
On the Moto G I have to wait the full 10 seconds, before I get an TIMEOUT error.

Is this a bug? And if yes, who is responsible: Cordova, the WebView, or Android?
Is there any workaround using cordova? Or do I have to add some java code or a plugin?

Another question is: what about other platforms - will the code above work or not?

It seems, that there IS a way to detect geolocation availability with Android / Java.
When running the GPS Status App on the Moto G I will be notified immediately about a deactivated GPS.

Here's the output of my two devices, running my cordova app:

```
Huawei:
got an error:
code   : 2
message: The last location provider was disabled
error.PERMISSION_DENIED    = 1
error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE = 2
error.TIMEOUT              = 3
error.UNKNOWN_ERROR        = undefined


Moto G:
got an error:
code   : 3
message: Timeout expired
error.PERMISSION_DENIED    = 1
error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE = 2
error.TIMEOUT              = 3
error.UNKNOWN_ERROR        = undefined
```

Cordova version is 3.5.0-0.2.7